# Replace a given string in folders throughout a directory

Tags: perl, bash

I want to do the equivalent of this, but [maybe recursively] for all, say, .md files within a directory tree.

```
perl -pi -e 's/FOO/BAR/g' *.md
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find /path -name "*.md" -exec perl -pi -e 's/FOO/BAR/g' {} \;
```

Comment: thank you! worked great!                                               (as i was in the right directory already, I changed '/path' to './', in case any readers are confused)

Answer (score 0):

A simple & pure bash one line solution by using [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace):

```
  $ cd ~/
  $ mkdir test
  $ cd test/
  $ touch foo{1..10}.md
  $ ls
    foo1.md  foo10.md  foo2.md  foo3.md  foo4.md  foo5.md  foo6.md  foo7.md  foo8.md  foo9.md

  $ for file in ./*.md; do mv "$file" "${file/foo/bar}"; done
  $ ls
    bar1.md  bar10.md  bar2.md  bar3.md  bar4.md  bar5.md  bar6.md  bar7.md  bar8.md  bar9.md
```

Of course it can be combined with `find` as suggested by devnull:

```
  $ files=($(find ./test -name "*.md"))
  $ for file in "${files[@]}"; do mv "$file" "${file/foo/bar}"; done
```

Or pipe the ouptut of `find` to the loop:

```
  $ find ./test -name "*.md" | for file in $(xargs -0); do mv "$file" "${file/foo/bar}"; done
```